# Deploy code from Bitbucket to EC2

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

I am using BitBucket for my Django project and EC2 for cloud servers. My objective is that when I push a commit to a branch, BitBucket will make a call on the hook and the hook will update the code in EC2.

So far, when I commit, the hook is called but the code isn't being updated on the server. In my understanding, this is to do with permissions in Linux/Ubuntu 14.04.

I have tried to follow the link from [Brandon Summers](http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/) and further refinement of the same by going [here](https://bitbucket.org/itjgray/bitbucket-php-deploy/src/4afec57d5d00083c15a4625c219874b830e097b5?at=master). But it still doesn't work.

With the first link, I get this in the log:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
chmod: cannot access '.git': No such file or directory
[Thu Jul 30 18:21:05.106127 2015] [:error] [pid 9736] [client 131.103.20.165:42727] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Deploy::$_data in /var/www/html/deploy_home.php on line 127
```

And the second link gives me this in console:

```
[Sat Aug 01 15:26:35.000824 2015] [:error] [pid 2447] [client 131.103.20.165:39102] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/deploy/deployments.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/deploy_repo.php on line 144
[Sat Aug 01 15:26:35.000869 2015] [:error] [pid 2447] [client 131.103.20.165:39102] PHP Warning:  chmod(): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/deploy_repo.php on line 147
[Sat Aug 01 15:26:35.000924 2015] [:error] [pid 2447] [client 131.103.20.165:39102] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/deploy/deployments.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/deploy_repo.php on line 152
[Sat Aug 01 15:26:35.001010 2015] [:error] [pid 2447] [client 131.103.20.165:39102] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/deploy/deployments.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/deploy_repo.php on line 144
[Sat Aug 01 15:26:35.001034 2015] [:error] [pid 2447] [client 131.103.20.165:39102] PHP Warning:  chmod(): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/deploy_repo.php on line 147
[Sat Aug 01 15:26:35.001068 2015] [:error] [pid 2447] [client 131.103.20.165:39102] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/log/deploy/deployments.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/deploy_repo.php on line 152
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
```

The second link's console output has something to do with unable to write to the log file but still the repo folder remains unchanged on EC2.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

First, I guess you are missing the `deploy` directory in `var/log`. Try to create it manually. In this way at least you will have some log files to analyze.

Second, you haven't shown your script here but it's worth mentioning this script is using the older Bitbucket IP; if you haven't changed it yet, try to replace the IP in this line,

```
 private $_repositoryIp = array ( '63.246.22.222');
```

with one of the new IP addresses you can find [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/What+are+the+Bitbucket+IP+addresses+I+should+use+to+configure+my+corporate+firewall).

Third, why all the effort when you can CI tools like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)? Some useful posts: [1](http://felixleong.com/blog/2012/02/hooking-bitbucket-up-with-jenkins), [2](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2014/integrating-bitbucket-and-jenkins.html).

Comment: I did create the `deploy` directory and continuously received a `permission denied` error. So, for testing purposes, I set it to `777` and this is what got logged in the file:
`exception 'Exception' with message 'Error 1 executing shell script' in /var/www/html/deploy_repo.php:173
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/deploy_repo.php(205): Deploy->execute()
#1 {main}`

Comment: It' failing here:  `exec("sudo -u {$this->_deployUser} {$this->_deployScript} 2>&1", $output, $return);` - I think it's because of permission issues; are you sure you have added `deploy` user to your sudoers? If not please follow [these](https://bitbucket.org/itjgray/bitbucket-php-deploy/src/4afec57d5d00083c15a4625c219874b830e097b5/deploy-sh.php?at=master) guidelines at the top of the script and make sure you have done everything in the correct way.